# Title Attribute Dropdown

Tags: html, css, title

I can't alter the HTML in order to remove the title attributes on this page [jn-racing.de](http://www.jn-racing.de)  on the dropdown navigation.

How can I disable all title attributes? Or format it with CSS to hide the tooltip on the hover

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885920/jquery-hide-title-attribute-but-not-remove-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Removing title attributes from WordPress links](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201011/removing_title_attributes_from_wordpress_links/) (456 Berea Street)

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the `title` attribute from the link in your markup.
If you can't, then css won't help. You'll need to hide it with javascript somehow.
In jQuery for example:

```
$('.menu a').removeAttr('title');
```

Comment: can i put it in the PHP file  on any place ?

Comment: Well, it's Javascript. So yes, if you escape php and add it inside a script tag it should work. `?><script>$(function(){ $('.menu a').removeAttr('title');
 });</script><?php`. Of course, you'll need to call the jQuery library too.

Comment: I think the problem is the shalian dropdown widget in wordpress

Comment: Then you can probably find the markup easily in the plugins' code and remove the `title` attribute.

Comment: I took a look at this but there is nothing and i´ve deleted all stuff of that