# After customizing css for tooltip, it is showing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After customizing the CSS for tooltip msg, it showing twice in the screen. Below is the kind of implementation provided.

```
<a href="#" title="This is some information for our tooltip." class="tooltip">
    <span title="More">CSS3 Tooltip</span>
</a>
```

```css
.tooltip {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover:after {
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 220px;
}

.tooltip:hover:before {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    top: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Sample Output:

[image]

Help me to find the cause of this and how can we suppress the 2nd tooltip msg

jsfiddle ([sample view](https://jsfiddle.net/tamjpzdq/5/))

Comment: Just remove the `title` attribute of inner span.

Comment: I removed but still same, see updated JSFiddle link, I updated in the question

Comment: Do `data-title` instead of `title` in css and html both

Comment: Sorry but I can't replace title with data-title as this title attribute is dynamically getting generated in Dyna-tree

Answer (score 7):

You're using CSS only "extends" the functionality for the title, but the original title attribute is still getting rendered.

You might wanna change it to `data-title` which isn't rendered by the browser by default, and change the CSS to `content: attr(data-title)` to use that instead.

Also, remove the inner span's title, it's redundant and unecessary.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tamjpzdq/6/)

Comment: Sorry but I can't replace title with data-title as this title attribute is dynamically getting generated in Dyna-tree

Comment: Thanks @casraf for sharing your idea. I used your approach and dynamically replaced title with data-title. I shared my approach for getting solution, which may help someone

Answer (score 2):

Use `data-title` attribute instead of `title`.

```
<a href="#" data-title="This is some information for our tooltip." class="tooltip"><span title="More">CSS3 Tooltip</span></a>
```

And, extract content of this attribute in your css.

```
content: attr(data-title);
```

EDIT:

If you have no control over the title attribute, you could remove them during runtime using JavaScript.

```
var tooltipElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip'));

tooltipElements.forEach(replaceTitleWithDataTitle);

function replaceTitleWithDataTitle(element) {
    var title = element.getAttribute('title');

    element.removeAttribute('title');
    element.setAttribute('data-title', title || '');
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't replace title with data-title as this title attribute is dynamically getting generated in Dyna-tree

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution, so I am sharing here, it might help someone else:
I applied same approach what is suggested in most of the answer i.e.

> You might wanna change it to data-title which isn't rendered by the
>   browser by default, and change the CSS to content: attr(data-title) to
>   use that instead.

With add-on to above I did below changes.

After page loading dynamically do below

- add `data-title` attribute by copying content of `title` attribute
- then remove the `title` attribute

**Below is sample code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tooltip").hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("data-title", $(this).attr("title"));
    $(this).removeAttr("title");
  }, function(){
    $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("data-title"));
    $(this).removeAttr("data-title");
  });
});
```

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/emG6E/102/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the title (not switching to data-title permanently) you could use javascript to remove and reset the attribute on hover.
See: [jquery: hide title attribute but not remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885920/jquery-hide-title-attribute-but-not-remove-it)

Or much easier use: aria-label

```
<a href="#" aria-label="This is some information for our tooltip." class="tooltip">
   <span>CSS3 Tooltip</span>
</a>
```