# Image tool tip with html elements and styes

Tags: html, css

When I hover the image, Instead of showing the image title/tooltip, its showing the entire html related to that image, including the styles. Attached the screenshot of the same.
[image]

We have done it such a way that , the title comes like this, when the image popsup on click

[image]

```
 title="<h2 style='position: absolute;top: -35px;font-size: 13px;left:    0;color: #fff;width: 100%;font-weight:bold;'><?php echo $portfolio['portfolio_title']; ?></h2><p style=position: absolute;top: -5px;left: 0%; width: 100%;margin:0!important; font-size:12px!important;'><?php echo $portfolio['portfolio_description']; ?></p>"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your *title* attribute of the image is bugged with wrong HTML. Post your HTML for a proper solution

Comment: You can't style the title attribute

Comment: Yes! , but is there a way to hide it on hover. Since the plugin uses that title to show the Image Name / Headline as seen on the second image. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Put the thing you want viewed as a **title** in your image tag.

`<img src="x" title="What you want showed"/>`

Comment: I have updated my query. We are using a plugin for the popup. And it has a title option, which serves as the title /headline, when the larger image is shown

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for your problem is: Create a separate div and style that accordingly and hide it by default from CSS/JS. When hover over on the image make it visible.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.wrapper:hover .hover-element {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.hover-element {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="" />

  <div class="hover-element">
    <h2>Tooltip Text</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adip</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7pw4djx/)

Comment: Hi Anwar, Thanks for the support. Is there any option to hide the title on hover.

Comment: You mean you want to use HTML title attribute instead of creating separate div? There's also another way, you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Anwar, What I meant was to use some Javascript to hide title display (Only on hover). Thank you

Comment: Well, you can remove title attribute using jQuery. `$('p').removeAttr('title');`

Where `p` is your HTML tag!

Comment: Would this hide title on hover?

Comment: It'll remove the title.

Comment: You also can try this fiddle to just hide on hover, but it'll stay on the html: http://jsfiddle.net/2nHxV/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the support. I was able to resolve the issue by using  the script from another stack overflow  question.

[jquery: hide title attribute but not remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885920/jquery-hide-title-attribute-but-not-remove-it)

I used Ridwan Pujakesuma answer to solve it.

Thanks again

Regards
Gops