# How can we set display none css styling to title attribute in html?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to set the css style display none on title attribute. But the whole portion is affecting display none. Sample codes are here

```
<input type="file" name="ctl15$rptCareerModal$ctl00$CareerFileUpload" id="ctl15_rptCareerModal_ctl00_CareerFileUpload" title="1" class="CareerFile">
<style>input[title]{ display : none;}</style>
```

Comment: what exatally you want to do ?

Comment: This is an answerable question. Please remove the minus marks.

Comment: @chirag patel - I need to keep the title attribute there. But don't need to display while mouse hover.

Comment: Check this answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885920/jquery-hide-title-attribute-but-not-remove-it

Comment: No this is not what i need. Can be done by css not jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding title tags on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078388/hiding-title-tags-on-hover)

Comment: using css it is not possibel , you have to manage with jquery

Comment: @chiragpatel -  Can you explain why it is not possible ?

Comment: there is no css to change attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this you want to achieve, sir?

```js
$( "input" ).hover(
  function() {
$(this).data("title", $(this).attr("title")).removeAttr("title");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="ctl15$rptCareerModal$ctl00$CareerFileUpload" id="ctl15_rptCareerModal_ctl00_CareerFileUpload" title="1" class="CareerFile">
```

Comment: I have searched for it, but I couldn't really find any solution by using purely CSS.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

input[title]{ display : none;}

This syntax will hide all input types with any title. So, your whole portion is getting affected.
Please, give your exact requirement so that one can give correct code.

Comment: My requirement is to hide the title attribute value on input tag while hover in css.